How to Scale YOLOv8 Inference using Databricks
I have successfully trained a YOLOv8 model using the Ultralytics Python package and now aim to run inference on 100 million images stored in an S3 bucket. Currently, I have a Databricks notebook with GPU acceleration that performs inference, but I don't know how to scale this.
From the Databricks documentation, I gathered that using Databricks Autoloader to fetch images from S3 and MLflow to manage the model could help in scaling the batch inference process.
How can I efficiently scale the batch inference process for 100 million images in Databricks?
Should I use MLflow to manage and scale the inference jobs?
The current setup is running multiple notebooks with dedicated compute, which seems inefficient.

if scale the inference you have to distribute the inference over the executors. In this process, it doesn't really matter how fast your inference is. It is way more important to scale up your cluster in terms of cores. Then you can use an applyInPandas function to distribute the inference over the executors. In my point of view, you should also avoid storing all the images in your memory because if you have a lot of images you will need a big cluster which costs way more money because you can't scale up compute optimized.
Here is a rough idea of how I did it.
create partition column:
partition_value = 10000

sdf = sdf.withColumn(
    "id_tmp", (F.col("unique_id") % partition_value).cast(IntegerType()) 
)

partitioning:
num_partitions = sdf.select("id_tmp").distinct().count()

sdf_repartitioned = sdf.repartition(num_partitions, "id_tmp")

apply function:
def wrapper_yolo_inference(image_col):
    def apply_yolo(pdf):

        model = YOLO("weights.pt")

        pred = []

        for _, row in pdf.iterrows():   

            image_path = row[image_col]

            results = model(image_path)

            # take out what you need
            pred.append({ key: value,})
 
        return pd.DataFrame(pred)

    return apply_yolo

apply the applyInPandas and don't forget to define the output schema
sdf_yolo_result = sdf_repartitioned.groupby("id_tmp").applyInPandas(
    wrapper_yolo_inference("path"),  
    schema=ApplyInPandasSchema
)

You could also write a class to store the model in mlFlow and then you could use this pyfunc model function in your applyInPandas
And of course, in the apply function you can handle the inference part as you want to speed it up. It's basically giving little dfs to the executors
